# akka-http - Multipart/FromData stream batch size

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm receiving a `Multipart/FromData` as a server. This request contains `Source[Multipart.FormData.BodyPart, Any]` and each `Multipart.FormData.BodyPart` contains `Source[ByteString, Any]` inside. I'm able to set a buffer size. But it measures in elements count. How can I calculate the size of each ByteString element(batch size)? I need to calculate the whole buffer size in bytes.

```scala
entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) { formData => 
 formData
   .parts // Source[Multipart.FormData.BodyPart, Any]
   .flatMap { bodyPart => 
      bodyPart.entity.dataBytes.buffer(???, OverflowStrategy.backpressure) // Source[ByteString, Any]
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add `scala` tag to your questions in the future. Akka can be used in both java and scala. Thus this tag is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the motivation here is, but `buffer`'s cousin `batchWeighted` is likely to be what you want.

```scala
bodyPart.entity.dataBytes
  .batchWeighted[ByteString](
    max = 1024,    // bytes
    costFn = { bs: ByteString => bs.length },
    seed = { _: Any => ByteString.empty }
  ) { _ ++ _ }
```

(Have not tested this: my mental compiler says "looks good!")